# Creating VS solution without debug dll for Maya plug-in?

Tags: qt, cmake, maya

I'm trying to compile a custom plug-in for a software (Autodesk Maya) that has a custom version of Qt. The software provides a devkit with Qt files. It also contains the Qt stuff in its installation location.

Now I'm trying to generate a VS solution via cmake-gui:

- When I use the Qt stuff from the devkit, the binaries are missing, e.g. `Qt5Core.dll`.
- When I use the Qt stuff from the installation location, the debug binaries are missing, e.g. `Qt5Cored.dll`.

I have two questions:

- Why does the Maya devkit not contain the binaries? What is the point of the devkit then?
- Why does the Maya location not contain the debug binaries? Do I have to disable the referencing of debug binaries in cmake somehow?

Comment: Did you read this? https://around-the-corner.typepad.com/adn/2016/07/-maya-2017-devkit-building-qt-plug-ins-instructions.html

Comment: @VladimirBershov Yes now, I've made sure that only the includes and libs from the custom Qt version are used. I not sure about the qmake stuff. I'm compiling the plug-in with cmake and Visual Studio only. The plug-in doesn't contain anything that I can see that is related to qmake. [Here](https://github.com/alicevision/MeshroomMaya) it is ...

Comment: Maybe you can have a look at the autodesk open source tools: [OpenSource](https://www.autodesk.com/company/legal-notices-trademarks/open-source-distribution)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this:

https://help.autodesk.com/view/MAYAUL/2020/ENU/?guid=__developer_Maya_SDK_MERGED_Working_with_Qt_Using_Qt_in_Plug_ins_html

> This still leaves one potential problem area on Windows. Qt's QList
> template class provides inline methods which can create and destroy Qt
> objects. Because those methods are inlined, if they are called by
> plug-in code which has been built for debug, any objects created or
> deleted will use the memory allocator from the debug version of
> Microsoft's C Runtime Library. If the methods are called within Maya,
> they will use the release version of the C Runtime Library. Thus it is
> possible to get situations where objects are allocated within Maya
> using the release runtime library and deleted in the plug-in using the
> debug runtime library, or vice-versa. Since the release and debug
> versions of Microsoft's C Runtime Library are incompatible with each
> other, this can lead to crashes.

> At the moment, QList is the only Qt class we are aware of which has
> this potential for failure, but other Qt template classes could
> exhibit similar problems. To date, the only known workarounds are
> either to avoid the use of Qt template classes in your code, or to
> only **build your plug-in in release mode on Windows**.